# Unable to pin expand column at the left most in my Material React Table

Tags: reactjs, web, material-ui, tanstack, material-react-table

Iam using Material React Table in which I have to present my data in a tree like format. I just want to pin expand column (which collapses or expands rows) at the left most and after that I need to have my tasks column pinned.

I have successfully pinned my tasks column to the left but unable to pin expand column before it. Below is the component's code.

```
import React, { useMemo } from "react";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";

import { MaterialReactTable } from "material-react-table";

const CustomPaper = styled(Paper)({
  borderRadius: 10,
  marginTop: 20,
});

export const WBSTable1 = ({ datae = [], column = [] }) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <CustomPaper
        className={"paperCon"}
        sx={{
          width: "100%",
        }}
      >
        <MaterialReactTable
          columns={column}
          data={datae}
          enableExpanding
          enableExpandAll
          enablePinning
          initialState={{
            expanded: true,
            columnPinning: { left: ["tasks"] },
          }}
          positionExpandColumn={"first"}
          enableStickyFooter
        />
      </CustomPaper>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

And the data I'm Passing via props

```
export const wbsColumns = [
  {
    accessorKey: "tasks",
    header: "Tasks",
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "dave",
    header: "Dave",
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "simon",
    header: "Simon",
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "mehmet",
    header: "Mehmet",
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "ben",
    header: "Ben",
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "elon",
    header: "Elon",
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "shamir",
    header: "Shamir",
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "bryan_de_cout",
    header: "Bryan De Cout",
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "paul",
    header: "Paul",
  },
  {
    accessorKey: "joe",
    header: "Joe",
  },
];

export const wbsRow = [
  {
    id: 1,
    tasks: "Project Management",
    subRows: [
      {
        id: 2,
        tasks: "Project Management",
      },
      { id: 3, tasks: "QA/QC", mehmet: 15 },
      {
        id: 4,
        tasks: "Inter disciplinary design coordination",
        dave: 10,
      },
      { id: 5, tasks: "Utility Corridor coordination & NOC" },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    tasks: "Concept Design",
    subRows: [
      {
        id: 7,
        tasks: "Road Design",
        subRows: [
          { id: 8, tasks: "Plans and Profiles", simon: 40 },
          { id: 9, tasks: "Cross section" },
          { id: 10, tasks: "Turning Movement Design" },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You must specify this MRT column in the initialstate :

```
columnPinning: { left: ["tasks", "mrt-row-expand"] },
```

Others MRT columns may be used : https://www.material-react-table.com/docs/guides/display-columns#built-in-mrt-display-columns